# Is there any issues on hp zbook 14 ug6 with Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: hp

Actually I want to buy a laptop which is compatible for Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to use it on my daily programming tasks.

I am learning android development so if anyone having any issues with zbook 14 ug6 please answer your problems.

I know that almost every laptops has some issues with Ubuntu 22.04 but some of them can be resolved by using external drivers.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better fit for [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).